# post save operation if a filed is null or blank in django models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

here is my code :

```
class Invitation(models.Model):   
    #other fields here
    Code = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    Tags = models.ManyToManyField("CategorieInvitation", null=True, blank=True)
    Tags = models.ManyToManyField("Usage", null=True, blank=True)
    Note = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    Used = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    SendTo = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    # a revoir
    def post_save(self, model_instance, add):
        if self.Code.__len__() == 0 :
            self.Code = generate_invitation(1)[0]
            self.save()
```

how to replace Code with the result of generate_invitation if Code is blank or null even if created in django-admin interface ?

regards
Bussiere

Comment: the attributes of your model class are upercase, which would be confusing for readers and a violation of PEP 8. Unless this is part of your company's style guide, I would recomend using all lower case for attributes to be more in line with PEP8. Upercase tends to signify a class in Python.

Comment: What's with the 2! `Tags` fields? That's definitely not ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you are trying to do it's probably easier and more efficient to override the `save` method.

```
class Invitation(models.Model):   
    #other fields here
    code = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField("CategorieInvitation", null=True, blank=True)
    tags2 = models.ManyToManyField("Usage", null=True, blank=True)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    used = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    send_to = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    # a revoir

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.code:
            self.code = generate_invitation(1)[0]

        super(Invitation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

By the way `post_save` is not something that should be a model instance method.
See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/signals/#signals

Comment: Thanks yes it's that and yes i will normalize the models.